# protractor :how to select an element using xpath

Tags: protractor

i have this HTML 
[Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkQMQ.png)

```
<span aria-controls="APInvoicePaymentTerms_listbox">
```

and i'm trying to click on this element using this code :

```
           element(By.xpath('//span[@aria-controls="APInvoicePaymentTerms_listbox]')).click();
```

and i got this error

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, APInvoiceCompany_listbox)
```

Comment: try this `"//span[@aria-controls='APInvoicePaymentTerms_listbox]'")`

Comment: To start with, you have an unclosed `"`. Fix that and see if it works then.

Answer (score 3):

The logic is correct. There is a typo

```
       element(By.xpath("//span[@aria-controls='APInvoicePaymentTerms_listbox']")).click();
```